# maven の pom.xml に対して xmllint の xpath で要素を拾うことができない

Tags: xml, xpath

以下のような `dummy-pom.xml` ファイルを用意しました。

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dummy</groupId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <artifactId>dummy-pom</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

この状態から、 xmllint で、 xpath によって要素を取得しようとしたのですが、正しく動作してくれません。

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/project' dummy-pom.xml
XPath set is empty
```

これは、xpath の指定が間違っているのだと考えられますが、どう間違っているのかがわからずにいます。

#### 質問:

上記ファイルに対して xpath で要素を取得できないのはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: デフォルトの namespace を無効にしてしまう方法などを。`sed -e "s/xmlns=/ignore=/" dummy-pom.xml | xmllint --xpath '/project' -`

Comment: [xmllint failing to properly query with xpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264134/xmllint-failing-to-properly-query-with-xpath) と同じ質問ですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

既定の`xmlns`が指定されているので名前空間を指定しない`project`ではマッチしないと思われます。ローカル名で

```
/*[local-name()='project']
```

と判定するか、XMLに`xmlns:hoge="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"`のようにプレフィックスを定義してから`/hoge:project`とテストすべきではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

ネームスペースが設定されているためそのままの指定ではマッチしません。
[local-name()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms256070(v=vs.120).aspx)を使用する方法はすでにでていますので別の方法。
とにかく指定が長くなるので、
shellモードでsetnsでネームスペースの設定をします。
下の例ではxをプレフィックスとして設定します。

```
>xmllint --shell dummy-pom.xml
/ > setns x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
/ > xpath /x:project
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 1 nodes:
1  ELEMENT project
    default namespace href=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    namespace xsi href=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instan
    ATTRIBUTE schemaLocation
      TEXT
        content=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http:/...
/ > xpath //x:modelVersion/text()
Object is a Node Set :
Set contains 1 nodes:
1  TEXT
    content=4.0.0
/ >
```